# Powershell pass AzureDataFactory as Variable to function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass a PSDataFactory to a function in Powershell.
But i keep running into errors.
Here is the script.

```
function DeleteAPipeline ([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.PSDataFactory] $ldf, $lplName)
{
    try
    {
        $lpl  = Get-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline -DataFactory $ldf -Name $lplName -EA SilentlyContinue
        if ($lpl)
        {
            Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline -DataFactory $ldf -Name $lplName -Force
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ("Try-Catch during DeleteAPipeline : $($lplName)")
    }
}
$rgName = "RGR-LabScenario003"
$dfName = "df-cern-xml"
$path = "C:\Cernv2\" 
$AZcontext = "C:\CernV2\Powershell\ProfileContext.ctx" 

Import-AzureRmContext -Path $AZcontext

$df = Get-AzureRmDataFactory -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $dfName

DeleteAPipeline ($df, "ledw-BL_GT")
```

The error i'm getting is

```
DeleteAPipeline : Unable to find type [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.PSDataFactory].
```

Problem migth be that the declaration is wrong, but this is what I found on the function at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/get-azurermdatafactory?view=azurermps-4.4.1

But when i did not declare a 'type' and just wrote the function like function DeleteAPipeline ($ldf, $lplName) then the error becomes

```
Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactories.Models.PSDataFactory' required by parameter
```

Using that last reference results then is a strange error

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactories.Models.PSDataFactory".
```

So finnaly, i'm a bit confused how I should code this ...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You realize that you are referencing two different `PSDataFactory` types right? Notice that the second error (when you don't specify the type) starts with `Microsoft.Azure` and the first one starts with `Microsoft.WindowsAzure` for the types.

Comment: I know, but with none of them I get it working. Not being a real Powershell nor .NET developper I was wondering on how to find the right reference. The first was wat i did find on the help pages from Azure, the second one was in Powershell itself. I'm not experienced enough to understand what I should use.